# primefaces command button update inside data table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I want to add a click function with jquery to a commandButtons inside data tables rows, this button show a dialog which content I want to build with javascript. but the function defined in the javascript is not even called.

I have this:

```
<p:datatable id="tbl1">
<p:commandButton id="button1" onclick="dlg.show()">
</p:commandButton>
</p:datatable>
```

And in my javascript

```
$("#form:tbl1:0:button1").click(function(){
 //...some js functionality to show on the dialog
});
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated

Have a nice day everybody

Comment: Try `$("#form\\:tbl1\\:0\\:button1").click(function(){`.Because on the page if you don't do `\\` in the javascript, that wont be recognized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery uses [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) syntax to select elements in HTML DOM tree. The colon `:` is a special character in CSS selector syntax representing the start of a pseudo selector like `:hover`, `:active`, `:disabled`, `:first-child`, etc. However, you're using it here as part of the element ID, not as a pseudo selector. In that case, you need to escape the colon with a (double) backslash.

```
$("#form\\:tbl1\\:0\\:button1")
```

Alternatively, use plain JS `document.getElementById()` and pass its to jQuery, it just takes the plain element ID, not a CSS selector, so you don't need to escape it:

```
$(document.getElementById("form:tbl1:0:button1"))
```

Or better yet, give it a style class:

```
<p:commandButton ... styleClass="some-button" />
```

so that you can just do

```
$(".some-button")
```

and be able to reuse it on other buttons.